# NHibernate and JoinAlias throw exception

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have query in `HQL` which works good:

```
var x =_session.CreateQuery("SELECT r FROM NHFolder f JOIN f.DocumentComputedRights r WHERE f.Id = " + rightsHolder.Id + " AND r.OrganisationalUnit.Id=" + person.Id);
            var right = x.UniqueResult<NHDocumentComputedRight>();
```

Basically I receive NHDocumentComputedRight instance.

I've tried to implement the same query in QueryOver. I did this:

```
var right = _session.QueryOver<NHFolder>().JoinAlias(b => b.DocumentComputedRights, () => cp).Where(h => h.Id == rightsHolder.Id && cp.OrganisationalUnit.Id == person.Id)
            .Select(u => cp).List<NHDocumentComputedRight>();
```

But I get null reference exception.

How can I implement this query in `QueryOver`?

**Update (added mappings) - NHibernate 3.2:**

```
public class FolderMapping: ClassMapping<NHFolder>
    {
        public FolderMapping()
        {
            Table("Folders");
            Id(x => x.Id, map =>
            {
                map.Generator(IdGeneratorSelector.CreateGenerator());
            });
//more not important properties...

            Set(x => x.DocumentComputedRights, v =>
            {
                v.Table("DocumentComputedRightsFolder");
                v.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
                v.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Subselect);
                v.Lazy(CollectionLazy.Lazy);

            }, h => h.ManyToMany());


            Version(x => x.Version, map => map.Generated(VersionGeneration.Never));
            }
    }

public class DocumentComputedRightMapping : ClassMapping<NHDocumentComputedRight>
    {
        public DocumentComputedRightMapping()
        {
            Table("DocumentComputedRights");

            Id(x => x.Id, map =>
            {
                map.Generator(IdGeneratorSelector.CreateGenerator());
            });

//more not important properties...

            ManyToOne(x => x.OrganisationalUnit, map =>
            {
                map.Column("OrganisationalUnit");
                map.NotNullable(false);
                map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
            });

        }
    }

public class OrganisationUnitMapping : ClassMapping<NHOrganisationalUnit>
    {
        public OrganisationUnitMapping()
        {
            Table("OrganisationalUnits");
            Id(x => x.Id, map =>
                              {
                                  map.Generator(IdGeneratorSelector.CreateGenerator());
                              });

//more not important properties...

        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: does it work with `cp.OrganisationalUnit == person`?

Comment: no because problem is in .Select(U=>cp) part.  When I remove this (or change to Select(u=>cp.Id) then this query works.

Comment: is there a backreference in NHDocumentComputedRight to NHFolder?

Comment: there is no backreference to NHFolder. And this is ManyToMany relation.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK criteria/queryOver can only return the entity it was created for (NHFolder in your example) or columns which are set to entity with aliastobean. you could do a correlated subquery instead.

```
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<NHFolder>()
    .JoinAlias(b => b.DocumentComputedRights, () => cp)
    .Where(h => h.Id == rightsHolder.Id && cp.OrganisationalUnit.Id == person.Id)
    .Select(u => cp.Id);

var right = _session.QueryOver<NHDocumentComputedRight>()
    .WithSubquery.Where(r => r.Id).Eq(subquery)
    .SingleOrDefault<NHDocumentComputedRight>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the select statement, have you tried something like this:

```
var right = _session.QueryOver<NHFolder>()
    .JoinAlias(b => b.DocumentComputedRights, () => cp)
    .Select(x => x.DocumentComputedRights)
    .Where(h => h.Id == rightsHolder.Id && cp.OrganisationalUnit.Id == person.Id)
    .List<NHDocumentComputedRight>();
```

This is what is working for me so it should work in you case as well.

I would guess that the main reason behind the problem is the lack of proper overload on the `Select` method. In reality you would like to write it like this:

```
.JoinAlias(b => b.DocumentComputedRights, () => cp)
.Select(() => cp)
```

but the `Expression<Func<object>>` is not there. Hopefully it's going to be included in the next version.

Comment: I tried your query but I get this exception: [ SELECT this_.Id as y0_ FROM Folders this_ inner join DocumentComputedRightsFolder documentco3_ on this_.Id=documentco3_.nhfolder_key inner join DocumentComputedRights cp1_ on documentco3_.elt=cp1_.Id WHERE (this_.Id = @p0 and cp1_.OrganisationalUnit = @p1) ]
  Name:cp0 - Value:65536  Name:cp1 - Value:32769. But strange thing is that still this query (in sql) returns NHFolder id (this_.Id) and not NHDocumentComputedRights

Comment: and for your info this is ManyToMany relation between NHFolder and NHDocumentComputedRights

Comment: Can you paste your mappings as well? The generated sql does not seem correct - which version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: added mappings to the question. I skipped not important properties. I use NH 3.2